# Need to use withWhereHas in BelongsToMany Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-relations

I have belongsToMany relationship.

```
Projects
- id
- name

Users
- id
- name

project_user
- project_id
- user_id
```

```php
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withWhereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('name', ['Admin', 'Writer']);
    });
}
```

Now, need to add `withWhereHas` condition in relationship.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there's a new method in Laravel 10. `withWhereHas`.

> Project Model:

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        return $query->whereIn('name', ['Admin', 'Writer']);
    })->with('roles');
}
```